# SCP to Amazon Issue with Copy

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sh

Can someone help me figure out why I am getting the error: `/home/cpmove-XXXXX.tar.gz is not a directory`

I am attempting to batch package sites from one cpanel server to another existing on Amazon, here is my code... and the error above shows in between the `MOVING` and `DONE MOVING` (which is why I assume it's scp)

```
#!/bin/bash

# -------------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------------
# Setup the function that will do the actual backup
run_backup(){
    LOGFILE=/batch-move.log
    # Package the account
    ./scripts/pkgacct $1;
    echo '##########################################' >> $LOGFILE;
    echo "# Start: date +'%T'" >> $LOGFILE;
    echo "# Backing Up: $1" >> $LOGFILE;
    echo '##########################################' >> $LOGFILE;
    # Upload it to Server Specified on Amazon
    # 2nd Param = Server IP Address
    if [ ! -f MYPEMFILE.pem ]
        then
        wget http://MYSTI.COM/MYPEMFILE.pem;
    fi;
    sudo chmod 400 MYPEMFILE.pem;
    echo 'MOVING';
    scp -i MYPEMFILE.pem /home/cpmove-$1.tar.gz root@$2:/home /home/cpmove-$1.tar.gz;
    echo 'DONE MOVING';
    echo '##########################################' >> $LOGFILE;
    echo "# Uploading Backup: $1" >> $LOGFILE;
    echo '##########################################' >> $LOGFILE;
    echo '##########################################' >> $LOGFILE;
    echo "# Removing Backup Up: $1" >> $LOGFILE;
    echo "# Finish: date +'%T'" >> $LOGFILE;
    echo '##########################################' >> $LOGFILE;
}


# -------------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------------
# Use a space-delimited list of single-quoted
# strings of the usernames to batch
# if it's empty it will backup all user directories
# in /home
# -------------------------------------------------
# -------------------------------------------------
USER_ACCOUNT=();


# Loop through the user array
# If it's empty, then get all users in the /home 
# directory, based on each folder
# do not include root user
if [ ${#USER_ACCOUNT[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    for filename in /home/* ; do
        # Get the owner of $filename.
        ACCT=$(stat -c '%U' "$filename");
        # If the file is a directory NOT owned by root, run backup.
        if [ -d "$filename" -a "$ACCT" != "root" ]; then
            # Uncomment when satisfied
            run_backup $ACCT $1;
            # Remove the file from the server
            echo 'REMOVING /home/cpmove-$ACCT.tar.gz';
            /bin/rm -f /home/cpmove-$ACCT.tar.gz;
    fi;
    done;
else
    # we have our list, now loop through them all
    for i in ${!USER_ACCOUNT[@]}; do
        # Assign an account variable
        ACCT=${USER_ACCOUNT[$i]};
        run_backup $ACCT $1;
        # Remove the file from the server
        echo 'REMOVING /home/cpmove-$ACCT.tar.gz';
        /bin/rm -f /home/cpmove-$ACCT.tar.gz;
    done;
fi;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
scp -i MYPEMFILE.pem /home/cpmove-$1.tar.gz root@$2:/home /home/cpmove-$1.tar.gz;
```

You are telling scp to move `/home/cpmove-$1.tar.gz` and `root@$2:/home` to `/home/cpmove-$1.tar.gz` and since `/home/cpmove-$1.tar.gz` is not a directory scp cannot move multiple source files/directories to it.

Drop that final `/home/cpmove-$1.tar.gz` since it isn't what you want there.

Also you should quote your variable usages `"$1"` and `"$2"` etc.

Comment: omg!  what a tool.  LOL.  Thanks for this.    Why quote them?

Comment: @Kevin Because if they have spaces or shell wildcard characters in them then the shell will interpret them when unquoted. See the output from this for example `(set -x; f='kv1 kv2'; touch "$f"; ls $f; ls "$f"; rm "$f")`.